# Как загрузить war на сервер Tomcat в корень?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet

Собственно через стандартный "Application Manager" делаю deploy моего `helloworld.war` и получаю путь к сайту через `serverip/helloworld/`, а хотелось бы `serverip/` но по этому адресу окно приветствия Tomcat.

И вторая проблема. В 'inedx.jsp' приходится менять стороку `<form action="../LoginServlet" method="post">'` на `<form action="../helloworld/LoginServlet" method="post">`, что не очень удобно если класснов много.

Comment: У сервера приложений может быть параметр, устанавливающий contextPath web-приложения, который прописывается в дескрипторе, специфичном для сервера. Другой способ - это назвать helloworld.war каким-нибудь ROOT.war. Не знаю действует ли это правило для всех серверов или у каждого, как и в первом варианте тоже есть своя специфика. См. мануалы по tomcat-у, способ точно есть. Для приложений ear есть стандартный для всех способ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, задавайте в следующий раз в одном вопросе один вопрос, а не два.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждое веб-приложение в Tomcat разворачивается в свой контекст. Чтобы разместить свое приложение в корневом контексте у вас есть следующие варианты:

1. Удалить директорию `webapps/ROOT`, а свой WAR-ник назвать `ROOT.war`.
2. Либо сконфигурировать раздел `<Host>` файла `conf/server.xml` следующим образом:

   ```
   <Context path="" docBase="your_app_name">
       <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
   </Context>
   ```
3. Либо поставить перед Tomcat-ом реверс-прокси (nginx), что обычно и происходит на боевых серверах, и делать подмену url-ов.

---

Что до второй проблемы, обычно ее решают так:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/LoginServlet">
```

либо при помощи [`<c:url>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html)

Comment: Я так понимаю все три варианта подразумевают доступ к файловой системе сервера? А если мне в качестве хостинга выдали только ip на котором поднят TomCat? Это можно как-то настроить через стандартные средства вебморды?

Comment: То есть у вас не VPS, этот томкат шарится и на нем сидите не только вы?

Comment: Это не VPS но сижу только я)

Comment: Кстати, подскажите, как в в сервлете правильно задать путь для jsp? по анологии с `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/LoginServlet`? я делаю такой запрос но файл нот фаунд `resp.sendRedirect("/jsp/success.jsp");`. PS LoginServlet уже заработал, спасибо

Comment: Никогда так не делал, но если вы деплоите через Tomcat Manager, попробуйте в поле `Context Path` вписать `/`. И раздеплойте перед этим, то что уже развернуто в `/` (первая строка в таблице).

Comment: Возьмите `HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()`

Comment: В целом понятно. Буду писать в поддержку. Спасибо.